# Get all rows in a Pandas DataFrame column that are in a list of strings - This pattern has match groups

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, python-2.7

Consider the code

import pandas as pd

```
# dfs
df_sample = pd.read_csv('...........')
array = ['' , '' , '' ....]

pattern = '|'.join(array)
# get all the rows
print(df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.str.contains(pattern))
```

How can I get the column's contents and not TRUE/FALSE as at the moment ?

Since I keep getting this:

```
manipulations.py:17: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  print(df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.str.contains(pattern))
0        False
1         True
2        False
3          NaN
4          NaN
         ...  
10942    False
10943      NaN
10944      NaN
10945      NaN
10946      NaN
Name: COLUMN_NAME_XXX, Length: 568743243, dtype: object
```

Comment: the UserWarning says to use `str.extract`, did you try with that? it would be easier if you actually share a couple of input rows and your expected output depending on your array of patterns

Comment: try this: `df_sample[df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.str.contains(pattern)]` . it will give you those filtered rows that contain the pattern you specified.

Comment: @MEdwin: It gives `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try via `fillna()`:

```
m=df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.str.contains(pattern).fillna(False)
#Finally:
out=df[m]
#OR
out=df.loc[m]
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your filtered dataframe

Comment: How can I force the `contains` to return only results that are whole words in the Pattern ?

Comment: @JAN Then use `isin()` instead of `str.contains()` `m=df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.isin(array)`

Comment: @JAN check again notice I am passing list named `array` not `pattern` in `isin()` in the above commenr

Comment: OK ,thanks! One last thing , I need to have the other way around, meaning checking if one of the elements of the `array` is in the column , and not if the column in the array... care to enlighten a little bit ?

Comment: @JAN you can do: `df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.map(lambda x:True if x in array else False)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass that logical array directly back to the dataframe slicing operators, like:

```py
df_sample[df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.str.contains(pattern)]
```

Which should return all rows where the condition inside the square brackets is satisfied. Conditions can be chained by formatting them like:

```py
[(condition1) | (condition2)]  #OR
[(condition1) & (condition2)]  #AND
```

It seems to map NaN to False automatically, but if not you can add that as another step to the boolean dataframe by adding .fillna(value = False):

```py
df_sample[df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.str.contains(pattern).fillna(value = False)]
```

Comment: Shoots `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`

Comment: Ok, so you need to replace the NaN values with False. Try adding .fillna(value = False) to the condition to make it: df_sample[df_sample.COLUMN_NAME_XXX.str.contains(pattern).fillna(value = False) ]